# How can you print instruction in llvm

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

From an llvm pass, I need to print an llvm instruction (Type `llvm::Instruction`) on the screen, just like as it appears in the llvm bitcode file. Actually my compilation is crashing, and does not reach the point where bitcode file is generated. So for debugging I want to print some instructions to know what is going wrong.

Comment: off topic: I like the way you're still using the generated name for about 3 years..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By simply using the `print` method.

Comment: Can you give an example? Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Assuming I is your instruction

```
I.print(errs());
```

Answer (score 0):

For a simple Hello World program, using C++'s range-based loops, you can do something like this:

```
      for(auto& B: F){
        for(auto& I: B){
            errs() << I << "\n";
        }
      }
```

This gives the output:

```
  %3 = alloca i32, align 4
  %4 = alloca i8**, align 8
  store i32 %0, i32* %3, align 4
  store i8** %1, i8*** %4, align 8
  %5 = call i32 (i8*, ...) @printf(i8* getelementptr inbounds ([15 x i8], [15 x i8]* @.str, i64 0, i64 0))
  ret i32 0
```